# Omit undefined values when creating object literal

Tags: typescript

Say the interface has an optional property:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
  bar: string|undefined;
}
```

We have a value that might be undefined:

```
makeFoo(bar: string|undefined) {
   const foo = '123';
   return { foo, bar }; // but omit "bar" property if bar === undefined
}
```

Is it possible for creating the object literal to automatically omit properties with undefined values?

Answer (score 2):

The best hack I've found for this type of situation so far is leveraging the `...` object spread syntax

```
function makeFoo(bar: string | undefined) {
  const foo = "123";
  return { foo, ...(bar && { bar }) };
}
```

Here's a Typescript [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDc%20yARnFKRVSNcgD7ICuIACYQYoCIPoBfXLhgCEYYOhDIAtnADWEDOgAUzVuUo0e-ISLGCAlDgYJlFQpmQBeZACIAjACYAzO-oCKAgwPigVbCd0ABpkADoE-RZkADIUnCZkyRtJWmQAenymPjBkdFVgUvcDd2QAByh0OugwAE9kYBhMqFcXNwFhURBxXGkZexAydAAbCDjp9GpddS0dXQGLYesrIA) where you can give it a go. Admittedly, for more than two properties like this you may be better served by building the object from a collection of key/value pairs like `Object.fromEntries` and then filtering it.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially a JavaScript question

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
}

function makeFoo(bar?: string): Foo {
   const foo = '123';
   if(typeof bar !== 'string') {
     return { foo };
   }
   return { foo, bar };
}
```

The problem is that TypeScript cannot omit `bar`, since `bar` is omitted on run-time, you could return `bar` as `undefined`, but then a problem arises when you use `Object.keys(makeFoo())`, because then the `bar` key will appear as a key, so you need to make sure you return an object on run-time that doesn't have `bar` at all